# Регулярные выражения RegEx для Украинских мобильных телефонов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, сопоставление-с-образцом

Регулярка не справляется

```
`/^((\+)?(3)?(8)?[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?\d{3}[\- ]?\d{2}[\- ]?\d{2}$/`
```

Необходимо, чтобы регулярка проверяла и пропускала следующие варианты введённых мобильных телефонов:

+38 (063) 123-45-67

+38(063) 123-45-67

+380631234567

+38-063-123-45-67

380631234567

80631234567

0631234567

И остальные, которые пересекаются!

В данный момент, регулярка может пропустить +3806312345. Прошу помощи! Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы забыли еще варианты

+380 (63) 123-45-67

+380 63 123-4-567

Я бы вначале облегчил себе задачу, выбросив из строки все разделители. Тогда все станет просто

```js
function checkNumber(AStr) {
  AStr = AStr.replace(/[\s\-]/g, '');
  return AStr.match(/^((\+?3)?8)?((0\(\d{2}\)?)|(\(0\d{2}\))|(0\d{2}))\d{7}$/) != null;
}

function showCheck(AStr) {
  console.log(checkNumber(AStr));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="tel" />
<button id="test" onclick="showCheck(document.getElementById('tel').value)">Test</button>
```

А если убрать скобки, то еще проще

```
function checkNumber(AStr) {
  AStr = AStr.replace(/[\s\-\(\)]/g, '');
  return AStr.match(/^((\+?3)?8)?0\d{9}$/) != null;
}
```

Comment: очень хороший подход, попробую, отдам тестеру

Comment: @reFactorPro Если мой ответ решил Вашу задачу, отметьте его как верный

Comment: покажите, как можно применить на практике к конкретному input type="tel"

Comment: @reFactorPro что применить?

Comment: Вашу функцию. Допустим, в качестве аргумента я вношу элемент input type="tel", в итоге мне выдаёт null

Comment: @reFactorPro Функция принимает строку. И передавать ей нужно значение `input.value`

Comment: то есть, нужно проверять после каждого введённого значения? on keyup?:

Comment: @reFactorPro я не знаю Вашей задачи и я понятия не имею когда Вам нужно проверять введенное значение

Comment: разобрался! Очень благодарен! Теперь при blur проверяется, и если юзер ввёл какие-то лишние символы, то они удаляются и потом происходит проверка по регулярке. Также при отправке происходит проверка по паттерну.